# Trying to find integral of square root function.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the integral of $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{6}}x \sqrt{36-6 x^2}$. When I use the substitution rule, I get $u = 36-6x^2$, which results in an imaginary number: $\dfrac{1}{12}u^{3/2} du$

My textbook suggests me to use $u = -36 + 6x^2$, but I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Wolfram software package *Mathematica* or shall I move your question to [Math.SE]?

Comment: Please move to mathematics. Thanks

Comment: Why is it an imaginary number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct substitution, it is just working out the integral:

$$\int_0^\sqrt{6} x\sqrt{36-6x^2}\,dx$$

Let $u=36-6x^2$ so $du=-12x \,dx$.

$$\int_{36}^0-\frac{\sqrt{u}}{12}\;du$$

$$\frac{1}{12}\int_0^{36}\sqrt{u}\;du$$

$$\frac{2u^{3/2}}{36}|_0^{36}=12$$